# Is it possible to send the plot output (mplfinance as mpf) to an email adress?

Tags: python, email, output, mplfinance

I am plotting the following charts with:

```
 mpf.plot(dfnew_plot,volume=True,style='starsandstripes',datetime_format=' %d-%m',alines= 
 two_points,addplot=apdict,xrotation=45,title=(stock),type='candle',ylabel='ROC5= '+(ROC5) +' ' 
 +'ROC20= '+(ROC20)+ ' ' +'ROCmean= '+(ROCmean),figscale=0.5)
```

- Is it possible to send only the plot output automatically to my email adresse, within the python script in a Jupyter Notebook?
- Is it possible to save only the plot output automatically as a html file or pdf?

[image]

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 2):

Mplfinance allows you to save the plot to a file (pdf, png, jpg, etc.)

See *and read all of* the documentation here: https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/savefig.ipynb

Once you have saved it to a file, you can send the file as an email attachment.
See here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html

In general you can learn a lot by going through the mplfinance documentation here: https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance#contents-and-tutorials

hth

Comment: I am plotting 100 Charts with a loop - each Nasdaq100 Stock. I would like to save this charts in one pdf. I am not able to see an example in the documentation. But I am a beginner.

Comment: Multipage PDF question is answered here: https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/issues/326#issuecomment-768706302